# Docker exec npm command

Tags: docker, npm, nvm

I have successfully build docker container with node in it.
When I ssh'd into it, npm, node commands works as expected, but when I'm trying to execute command remotely (`docker exec vvs_workspace npm install`), it prints `rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: exec: "npm": executable file not found in $PATH`

Dockerfile:

```
#####################################
# Node / NVM:
#####################################

ENV NVM_DIR=/home/dockuser/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 6.3.1

RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.3/install.sh | bash \
    && . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

RUN echo "" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo 'export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm' >> ~/.bashrc
```

P.S. when executing `docker exec vvs_workspace composer install` everything is ok.

Comment: same problem here.

Comment: Hi @rokas. Have you fixed this?

Comment: This might be useful for someone. `docker exec -it <container-name> bash`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/82 , just add `ENV PATH $PATH:/home/laradock/.nvm/versions/node/v6.8.0/bin` in your Dockfile.  change /home/laradock/.nvm/versions/node/v6.8.0/bin to your nvm path.